# TFS 2012 Builds and SQLite for WinRT

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2012, tfsbuild

Working on a Windows Store App which is utilising SQLite for WinRT. Local builds work fine due to the installation of the VS2012 Extension SQLite for Windows Runtime.

This adds 2 SDK references into the project config which points to the local file system (not part of the solution). But TFS 2012 Build freaks out saying that the build is broken as it can't find the SQLite and C++ dlls.

I am using the MS hosted TFS so installing the SDKs on the build server is not an option.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run across similar issues when trying to build WinRT projects using the TFS Hosted Build Server.

In the end, this article was the winner:

http://blog.novotny.org/2012/03/24/how-to-use-extension-sdks-per-project/

The solution is to put the libraries in version control in a “libs” directory. NuGet does this for existing libraries in a \packages directory at the solution-level; it does not yet support Extension SDKs. The good news is that both Visual Studio 11 and MSBuild already support defining additional locations for Extension SDK’s by overriding the SDKReferenceDirectoryRoot variable. The key is to add the override after the  element near the end of the csproj/vbproj file like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <SDKReferenceDirectoryRoot>$(SolutionDir)\libs;$(SDKReferenceDirectoryRoot)</SDKReferenceDirectoryRoot>
</PropertyGroup>
```

With that in place, you can then put your Extension SDK files alongside your solution:

\libs\Windows\v8.0\ExtensionSDKs[SDKName][SDKVersion]\…

Once there, it will be available in the Visual Studio Add References dialog like any other Extension SDK.

Now my SDK references don't need to be manually installed on developers machines or build servers.