# Is there any way to include extensions in TFS build?

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines

Nuget restorating is good when using CI in VSTS. However I am using some extensions like SQLite Runtime in my project. Is there any way to include those extension dlls other than referencing them in the project?

Comment: Did this fits your needs? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227147/tfs-2012-builds-and-sqlite-for-winrt

Comment: It actually does. I just wondered if there's any solution other than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides referencing them in the project which actually is the most recommended way.

You can also **manually install the extension on the build agent**. Just like how to use it in your local environment. Make sure the environment on the build agent is as same as your local.

**Check the extension and dlls in source control.** Even though we do not suggest to manage dlls for source control in TFS.

Answer (score 0):

Some packages (like redis for instance) have a "tools" folder which allows you to pull the "runtime" from nuget.
If your tool is not shipped as a nuget package you'll have either to:
- Include the tool on the source control (not the best thing if you want to keep the repo as small as possible)
- Install the tool on the build machine (only possible if you have your own agents and you're not using the hosted agent)
- Have a script to pull it from the web without relying on nuget (again really depends on the tool and if it has a "run without installation" version)
Hope that helps